# Django raw query - use dot notation for traversing related model's fields

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

This is my `raw` query in Django

```
q = Book.objects.raw('''
      SELECT * FROM 
        ( SELECT "book"."name", "author"."name", 
                 RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY "author"."id") AS "rank"
          FROM "book"
          INNER JOIN "book" ON ("book"."author_id" = "author"."id")
        ) AS "book_table"
      WHERE "rank" < %s ''', 10)
```

In the above queryset, the `name` field is ambiguous. I pass this object to another library which requires the usage of dot notation i.e. `q[0].name` should refer to the book's name and `q[0].author.name` should refer to author's name. Is it possible to use dot notation with raw query (last resort is using `"author"."name" AS "author_name"`, but that'll introduce redundant code because those functions take in input from Django's managed queries too, which support the dot notation).

Answer (score -2):

This would probably be better to use Django's own query syntax as much as possible, and only add the rank field manually. You can do this with `extra` rather than `raw`, and use `select_related` to traverse the relationship. Something like this:

```
Book.objects.select_related('author').extra(
    select={'rank': 'RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY "author"."id")'},
    where=['"rank" < 10']
)
```

Comment: I get an error : `ProgrammingError: column "rank" does not exist`. Won't I need a nested select for using `rank` in the where clause?  [According to docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html)  "Window functions are permitted only in the SELECT list and the ORDER BY clause of the query. They are forbidden elsewhere, such as in GROUP BY, HAVING and WHERE clauses....If there is a need to filter or group rows after the window calculations are performed, you can use a sub-select" ... Is that possible with `.extra()`?

Answer (score -2):

I think you are confused what `raw` means in the context of a `models.manager`.

You can use `FooModel.objects.raw` to create a queryset (actually a RawQuerySet) for FooModel; the result of the query passed into `raw` will be transformed into FooModels; therefore you should only return fields pertaining to FooModel. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries) in the docs for an example. Not sure what additional fields (like the author.name in your example) will do, but my guess is it will confused Django and not do what you intend it to do.

If you want to run completely arbitrary commands returning arbitrary data, you will need to drop to talking to the db directly like [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly).

In your case though, doing

```
q = Book.objects.raw('''
      SELECT "book"."id" FROM 
    ( SELECT "book"."id" 
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY "author"."id") AS "rank"
      FROM "book"
      INNER JOIN "book" ON ("book"."author_id" = "author"."id")
    ) AS "book_table"
  WHERE "rank" < %s ''', 10)
).prefetch_related("author")
```

should do what you want. It'll do one more query for fetching the authors than your original raw query would do, but that's probably acceptable in exchange of not having to deal with bare metal database queries.

Comment: Theoretically, your example sounds like it might work, but Django doesn't support it. I get an error : `RawQuerySet` object has no attribute `prefetch_related`. Secondly, not sure how do you conclude this : `you should only return fields pertaining to FooModel`. I've been able to join complex models & return their fields with raw query manager and they work fine.

Comment: Okay, then the RawQuerySet is rather limited and does not support anything beyond simple data access.

I doubt the raw query will actually use any fields beyond what is in the model, so while it works it will probably just refetch related objects.